# How to handle client or server side errors that occurred in placeholder renderings

Tags: jss, nextjs, jss-rendering-sdk

I am new to both Sitecore and next.js 13.5+
I created a scaffolded `nextjs` `jsssitecore` application using `npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs`

I am trying to create centralized error boundary. When there are errors(client or server side errors) in `src/pages/[[path]].tsx` or `src/Layout.tsx` then `_error.tsx` is been called and errors are gracefully handled. But if there any errors in `src/components/MyComp.tsx` for example errors are not gracefully handled instead they are thrown as runtime errors on UI. Placeholder rendering components are in src/components. Can anyone suggest me how to implement error handling for placeholder renderings. I tried using errorComponent but did not work. Attaching the code for placeholders
`Layout.tsx`

```
return (
    <>
      <Scripts />
      <Head>
        <title>{fields.pageTitle.value.toString() || 'Page'}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href={`${publicUrl}/favicon.ico`} />
        {headLinks.map(headLink => (
          <link rel={headLink.rel} key={headLink.href} href={headLink.href} />
        ))}
      </Head>

      <Navigation />
      {/* root placeholder for the app, which we add components to using route data */}
      <div className="container">
        {route && (
          **<Placeholder
            name="jss-main"
            rendering={route}
          />**
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );

MyComp.tsx
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    if (!inputValue) {
      // Throws error if input is empty
      throw new Error('Input cannot be empty!');
    }
    // ... form submission logic
  };
const MyComp = () => {
    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input id="myInput" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
}

export default MyComp;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Handle Component Level Errors you can use

1. Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in your component  e.g `{fields?.pageTitle?.value?.toString() || 'Page'}.` using optional chaining
2. You can even display a custom error page for the component if the error is thrown example of the code is shown below.

   ```
   import Error from 'next/error'

   export async function getServerSideProps() {
   const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
   const errorCode = res.ok ? false : res.status
   const json = await res.json()

   return {
    props: { errorCode, stars: json.stargazers_count },
    }
   }

   export default function Page({ errorCode, stars }) {
   if (errorCode) {
     return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
   }

   return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  We are using app router. Optional chaining is implemented but I want to handle runtime errors through errorboundary and unable to achieve it only for placeholder renderings

Comment: Your screen shot is showing pages router. If you are using JSS, that doesn't support app router yet.